# Ready-made solution for notification microservice

Tags: notifications, microservices

I have a microservice architecture and now I need to introduce a notification center. Requirements are: any service is able to send a notification, any service is able to subscribe to any kind of notifications, UI (web) is able to subscribe to notifications (websockets are preferred). Of course I can write such service by myself but maybe there is ready-made robust solution for that.

UPD: I'm not looking for pub/sub messaging system as it is too low-level for notification center

Comment: What you are looking for is a Publish/Subscribe (Pub/Sub) messaging solution

Comment: @AdamSiemion Pub/sub messaging system is just a... messaging system. It doesn't have enough abstractions (notifications types, grouping, etc) and web-api. So if I won't be able to find a ready-made service I'll write it by myself. Of course with underlying pub/sub messaging.

Comment: I am not sure if it helps but mayby it is good solution for you: https://commercetools.com/
They offer ready blocks in your micro services architecture

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is publish-subscriber messaging. If you are using AWS stack, then I can recommend Amazon SNS or Amazon SQS. I think Amazon SNS is more suitable because its push based.

> **Amazon SNS** allows applications to send time-critical messages to multiple subscribers through a “push” mechanism, eliminating the need
>   to periodically check or “poll” for updates.
>
> **Amazon SQS** is a message queue service used by distributed applications to exchange messages through a polling model, and can be
>   used to decouple sending and receiving components—without requiring
>   each component to be concurrently available.

Out of Amazon web services stack, there are a bunch of free messaging solutions:

> **RabbitMQ** is one of the leading implementation of the AMQP protocol (along with Apache Qpid). Therefore, it implements a broker
>   architecture, meaning that messages are queued on a central node
>   before being sent to clients. This approach makes RabbitMQ very easy
>   to use and deploy, because advanced scenarios like routing, load
>   balancing or persistent message queuing are supported in just a few
>   lines of code. However, it also makes it less scalable and “slower”
>   because the central node adds latency and message envelopes are quite
>   big.
>
> **ZeroMq** is a very lightweight messaging system specially designed for high throughput/low latency scenarios like the one you can find in
>   the financial world. Zmq supports many advanced messaging scenarios
>   but contrary to RabbitMQ, you’ll have to implement most of them
>   yourself by combining various pieces of the framework (e.g : sockets
>   and devices).
>
> **ActiveMQ** is in the middle ground. Like Zmq, it can be deployed with both broker and P2P topologies. Like RabbitMQ, it’s easier to
>   implement advanced scenarios but usually at the cost of raw
>   performance.

Now you know what you need, I would recommend to read through each technology for a while and decide which one serves your goal more accurately. If that doesn't worth our time and your requirement is more specific & relatively small, then you can go for writing something on your own.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm not looking for pub/sub messaging. I'd like to find ready-made notification center with web-api (maybe on top of pub/sub messaging). By the way you forgot to include kafka (as the most robust mq) into your list.

Comment: Only inside the amazon ecosystem